# Extra output during display listnode in c++

Tags: c++, display

For some odd reason when I attempt to display the range of my list it is giving extra output. The program asks for the user to enter the start and end node integers to display and then for some reason it will display a blank node and then the first node.  After about 10 seconds it will then display the correct range of nodes.

for instance, i would input

```
ball,   4,   9.99
doll, 2, 10.00
lava lamp, 5, 24.99
```

but when putting say a range of 2 to 3 it would output

```
2. (blank), (blank), (blank)
3. ball, 4, 9.99
(pause for 10 seconds that is not called for)
2. doll, 2, 10.00
3. lava lamp, 5, 24.99
```

Does anyone know why this may be? (The function in question is  void displayRange)

```
#include <iostream>
#define nullptr 0
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int menu();

class ItemList {
    private:
        struct ListNode{
            string IName;
            string QQuantity;
            string PPrice;
            double value;
            struct ListNode * next;
                };
ListNode *head;
    public:
        ItemList()
            {
                head = new ListNode;
                head->next=nullptr;
            }
            ~ItemList();

            void insertNode(string Item, string Quantity, string Price)
            {
                ListNode *newNode;
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *previousNode=nullptr;

                newNode=new ListNode;
                newNode->IName=Item;
                newNode->QQuantity=Quantity;
                newNode->PPrice=Price;

                if(!head)
                {
                    head=newNode;
                    newNode->next=nullptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodePtr=head;
                    previousNode=nullptr;

                    while(nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName < Item)
                    {
                        previousNode=nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                    if(previousNode==nullptr)
                    {
                        head=newNode;
                        newNode->next=nodePtr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousNode->next=newNode;
                        newNode->next=nodePtr;
                    }
                }
            }
            void displayNode()
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                nodePtr=head->next;
                int i=0;
                while(nodePtr)
                {
                    i++;

                    cout << i << ". " << nodePtr->IName << ",  ";
                    cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
                    cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
                    nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                }
                if(!head)
                {
                    cout << "The store is empty." << endl;
                }
            }

            void modifyNode(string Item)
            {
            ListNode *nodePtr;
            ListNode *nodePrev;
            string newName, newQuantity, newPrice;
            int modify;
            if (!head)
            {
                return;
                cout << "Store is empty." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                nodePtr = head;
                if (head->IName==Item)
                    nodePtr = head->next;
                else
                {
                    while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName != Item)
                    {
                        nodePrev = nodePtr;
                        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                    }
                }
                if (nodePtr)
                {
                    cout << nodePtr->IName << "\t" << nodePtr->QQuantity << "\t" << nodePtr->PPrice << endl;
                    cout << "What would you like to change?\n";
                    cout << "1. Item" << endl;
                    cout << "2. Quantity" << endl;
                    cout << "3. Price" << endl;
                    cout << "4. Whole Entry" << endl;
                    cin >> modify;
                    switch (modify)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin.sync();
                            getline(cin,newName);
                            transform(newName.begin(), newName.end(), newName.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->IName = newName;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin >> newQuantity;
                            transform(newQuantity.begin(), newQuantity.end(), newQuantity.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin >> newPrice;
                            transform(newPrice.begin(), newPrice.end(), newPrice.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            cout << "What is the product called?\n";
                            cin.sync();
                            getline(cin,newName);
                            transform(newName.begin(), newName.end(), newName.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->IName = newName;
                            cout << "How many are there really?\n";
                            cin >> newQuantity;
                            transform(newQuantity.begin(), newQuantity.end(), newQuantity.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                            cout << "What is the actual price?\n";
                            cin >> newPrice;
                            transform(newPrice.begin(), newPrice.end(), newPrice.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                    }
                }
                else
                    cout << "Product not found\n";
            }
        }

            void deleteNode(string Item)
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *previousNode;

                if(!head)
                    return;
                if(head->IName==Item)
                {
                    nodePtr=head->next;
                    delete head;
                    head=nodePtr;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodePtr=head;
                    while(nodePtr!=nullptr && nodePtr->IName!=Item)
                    {
                        previousNode=nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                    if(nodePtr)
                    {
                        previousNode->next=nodePtr->next;
                        delete nodePtr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Nothing to delete." << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

            void deleteRangeNode(int start, int stop)
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *newNode;
                nodePtr = head;
                int i=-1;
                cin.sync();
                while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
                {
                    i++;

                    if((i>=start)&&(i<=stop))
                    {
                        newNode->next = nodePtr -> next;
                        cout << "Deleted Product: " << nodePtr->IName << endl;
                        delete nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=newNode;
                    }
                    newNode=nodePtr;
                    nodePtr=nodePtr->next;


                }

            }

            void displayRange(int start, int stop)
            {
                ListNode * nodePtr;
                nodePtr=head;
                int i=-1;
                bool found=false;
                cin.sync();



                while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
                {
                    i++;
                    if((i>=start && i<=stop))
                    {
                        cout << i << ". " << nodePtr->IName << ",  ";
                        cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
                        cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


ItemList::~ItemList()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *nextNode;

    nodePtr=head;
    while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
    {
        nextNode=nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr=nextNode;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ItemList pro;
    int method;
    while(method!=0)
    {
    int method=menu();
    system("cls");
    string It, Q, P;
    int begin, end;
    switch(method)
    {
    case 1:
        int count;
        cout << "How many products would you like to put in?" << endl;
        cin >> count;
        system("cls");
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            cout << "Product #" << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Enter the item name: ";
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin,It);
            transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
            cout << "Enter the Quantity: ";
            cin >> Q;
            transform(Q.begin(), Q.end(), Q.begin(), ::toupper);
            cout << "Enter the Price: ";
            cin >> P;
            pro.insertNode(It, Q, P);
            cout << "\n";
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        int dis;
        cout << "How many products would you like to display?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Entire Store" << endl;
        cout << "2. Range of Products" << endl;
        cin >> dis;
        system("cls");
        switch(dis)
        {
            case 1:
                pro.displayNode();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "The display should START at: ";
                cin >> begin;
                cout << "The display should END at: ";
                cin >> end;
                pro.displayRange(begin,end);
                system("pause");
                break;
        }

        break;

    case 3:
        pro.displayNode();
        cout << "What product do you wish to modify? (by item name)" << endl;
        cin.sync();
        getline(cin, It);
        transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
        system("cls");
        pro.modifyNode(It);
        break;

    case 4:
        int del;
        cout << "Do you wish to delete one product or more?" << endl;
        cout << "1. One" << endl;
        cout << "2. Range of Products" << endl;
        cout << "3. Entire Store" << endl;
            cin >> del;
            system("cls");
            switch(del)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "What product do you wish to delete? (by item name)" << endl;
                    pro.displayNode();
                    cout << "\n";
                    cin.sync();
                    getline(cin,It);
                    transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
                    pro.deleteNode(It);
                    cout << "\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pro.displayNode();
                    cout << "What range of items do you wish to delete?" << endl;
                    cout << "START: ";
                    cin >> begin;
                    cout << "STOP: ";
                    cin >> end;
                    pro.deleteRangeNode(begin, end);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pro.~ItemList();
                    cout << "All items deleted." << endl;
                    break;
            }
        break;


    case 0:
        cout << "Exiting the program." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    string space1= "                       ";
    string space2= "                                  ";
    int method;
    cout << space1 << "What would you like to do to the store?" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "1. Add Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "2. Display" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "3. Modify Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "4. Delete Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "0. Exit\n" << endl;
    cout << space2;
    cin >> method;
    return(method);
}
```

Comment: For what input of *start* and *end* did that happen?

Comment: edited the post at the top

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that you are creating a sentinel node in the list, but then not ignoring it in `displayRange`. You are ignoring it when you call `displayNode`. The reason you are seeing the delay is because the loop in `displayNode` relies on signed integer overflow (which is undefined behavior) to terminate. Moving the increment of `nodePtr` outside of the range check will fix this.

There are several problems with this code. There are many reasons not to implement your own list container, but the most important one is because it's hard to get exactly correct the first time unless you are experienced with the language. I strongly encourage you to look into [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Here is a list of items I found.

1. `#define nullptr 0`  DO NOT DO THIS. The standard does not guarantee that this is well defined behavior, and the two do not have the same type.
2. Calling `cin.sync()` isn't guaranteed to do anything (it's implementation defined).
3. You need to clear the whitespace from the input stream before you try to call `std::getline` on it. This is covered in the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) under "Notes."
4. When inserting a new node, you need to set `newNode->next` to null.
5. Turn on your compiler's warnings. You have a several usages of uninitialized variables which can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: IIRC, the internal represention of a NULL pointer doesn't have to be all-zeros, but a *literal* `0` in a pointer context is required to be transformed at compile-time to the internal NULL pointer.  e.g. `while(p)` is guaranteed to be the same as `while(p != NULL)`.  The `#define` is still probably a bad idea, just not for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of blank node Problem:** insertion started at next-node of head in insertNode method. But, display started from head in displayRange method.

**Solution:** Resolve this mismatch !!! You can resolve this problem by changing ItemList as followings:

```
ItemList()
{
    head = nullptr; //changed here
}
```

**Cause of wrong range and late display Problems:** display pointer (nodePtr) is not updated accordingly.

**Solution:** Resolve this mismatch !!! You can resolve this problem by changing displayRange as followings:

```
void displayRange(int start, int stop)
{
    ListNode * nodePtr;
    nodePtr = head;
    int i = 0;  //changed here
    bool found = false;
    cin.sync();

    while (nodePtr != nullptr)
    {
        i++;
        if ((i >= start && i <= stop))
        {
            cout << i << ". " << nodePtr->IName << ",  ";
            cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
            cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
            //nodePtr = nodePtr->next;  //changed here
        }
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;    //changed here
    }
}
```

**I just pointed out the mention problems area, though it has some other bugs.**

Thanks !!!