# Extra Output into Text File

Tags: c++, linked-list, output

For some reason, when I am outputting my list to a text file, I am getting all of the nodes, except there is also an extra blank node being added to the beginning of the list like this:

```
(blank), (blank) $(blank)
Ball, 20 $9.99
```

How can I fix this? I have tried deleting head after the while loop and incrementing nodePtr/head to --, but to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#define nullptr 0
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


class ItemList {
    private:
        struct ListNode{
            string IName;
            string QQuantity;
            string PPrice;
            struct ListNode * next;
                };
ListNode *head;
    public:
        ItemList()
            {
                head = new ListNode;
                head->next=nullptr;
            }
            ~ItemList();

        void insertNode(string Item, string Quantity, string Price)
            {
                ListNode *newNode;
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *previousNode=nullptr;

                newNode=new ListNode;
                newNode->IName=Item;
                newNode->QQuantity=Quantity;
                newNode->PPrice=Price;

                if(!head)
                {
                    head=newNode;
                    newNode->next=nullptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodePtr=head;
                    previousNode=nullptr;

                    while(nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName < Item)
                    {
                        previousNode=nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                    if(previousNode==nullptr)
                    {
                        head=newNode;
                        newNode->next=nodePtr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousNode->next=newNode;
                        newNode->next=nodePtr;
                    }
                }
            }
        void displayNode()
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                nodePtr=head->next;

                int i=0;
                if(head->next==nullptr)
                {
                    cout << "The store is empty." << endl;
                }
                while(nodePtr)
                {
                    i++;
                    cout << i << ". " << nodePtr->IName << ", ";
                    cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
                    cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
                    nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                }

            }

        void modifyNode(string Item)
            {
            ListNode *nodePtr;
            ListNode *nodePrev;
            string newName, newQuantity, newPrice;
            int modify;
            if (head==nullptr)
            {

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                nodePtr = head;
                if (head->IName==Item)
                    nodePtr = head->next;
                else
                {
                    while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName != Item)
                    {
                        nodePrev = nodePtr;
                        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                    }
                }
                if (nodePtr)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << nodePtr->IName << "\t" << nodePtr->QQuantity << "\t" << nodePtr->PPrice << endl;
                    cout << "What would you like to change?\n";
                    cout << "1. Item" << endl;
                    cout << "2. Quantity" << endl;
                    cout << "3. Price" << endl;
                    cout << "4. Whole Entry" << endl;
                    cin >> modify;
                    switch (modify)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin.sync();
                            getline(cin,newName);
                            transform(newName.begin(), newName.end(), newName.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->IName = newName;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin >> newQuantity;
                            nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            cout << "Change to what?\n";
                            cin >> newPrice;
                            nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            cout << "What is the product called?\n";
                            cin.sync();
                            getline(cin,newName);
                            transform(newName.begin(), newName.end(), newName.begin(), ::toupper);
                            nodePtr->IName = newName;
                            cout << "How many are there really?\n";
                            cin >> newQuantity;
                            nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                            cout << "What is the actual price?\n";
                            cin >> newPrice;
                            nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                    }
                    newName=nodePtr->IName;
                    newQuantity=nodePtr->QQuantity;
                    newPrice=nodePtr->PPrice;
                    deleteNode(newName);
                    insertNode(newName, newQuantity, newPrice);
                    cout << "Entry successfully changed." << endl;
                }
                else
                    cout << "Product not found\n";
            }
        }

        void deleteNode(string Item)
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *previousNode;

                if(!head)
                    return;
                if(head->IName==Item)
                {
                    nodePtr=head->next;
                    delete head;
                    head=nodePtr;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodePtr=head;
                    while(nodePtr!=nullptr && nodePtr->IName!=Item)
                    {
                        previousNode=nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                    if(nodePtr)
                    {
                        previousNode->next=nodePtr->next;
                        delete nodePtr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Nothing to delete." << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

        void deleteRangeNode(int start, int stop)
            {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *newNode;
                nodePtr = head;
                int i=-1;
                cin.sync();

                while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
                {
                    i++;

                    if((i>=start)&&(i<=stop))
                    {
                        newNode->next = nodePtr -> next;
                        cout << "Deleted Product: " << nodePtr->IName << endl;
                        delete nodePtr;
                        nodePtr=newNode;
                    }
                    newNode=nodePtr;
                    nodePtr=nodePtr->next;


                }

            }




        void displayRange()
            {
                ListNode * nodePtr;
                nodePtr=head;
                int i=-1;
                int start, stop;

                if(head->next==nullptr)
                {
                    cout << "The store is empty." << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "The display should START at: ";
                cin >> start;
                cout << "The display should END at: ";
                cin >> stop;
                system("cls");
                while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
                {
                    i++;
                    if((i>=start && i<=stop))
                    {
                        cout << i << ". " << nodePtr->IName << ",  ";
                        cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
                        cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
                    }
                    nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                }
                }


            }

        void deleteAllNodes()
            {
                ListNode *temp = head;
                while(head->next!=nullptr)
                {
                    temp=head->next;
                    free(head);
                    head=temp;
                }
            }

        void keepNodes()
        {
            ofstream FinalInventory;
            FinalInventory.open("store.txt");
            ListNode *nodePtr;
            nodePtr=head;

            while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
            {
                FinalInventory << nodePtr->IName << ", " << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  $" << nodePtr->PPrice << endl;
                nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
            }
            delete head++;
            FinalInventory.close();
        }
};

ItemList::~ItemList()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *nextNode;

    nodePtr=head;
    while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
    {
        nextNode=nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr=nextNode;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int menu();
    ItemList pro;
    int method;
    while(method!=0)
    {
    int method=menu();
    system("cls");
    string It, Q, P;
    int begin, end;
    switch(method)
    {
    case 1:
        int count;
        cout << "How many products would you like to put in?" << endl;
        cin >> count;
        system("cls");
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            cout << "Product #" << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Enter the item name: ";
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin,It);
            transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
            cout << "Enter the Quantity: ";
            cin >> Q;
            transform(Q.begin(), Q.end(), Q.begin(), ::toupper);
            cout << "Enter the Price: ";
            cin >> P;
            pro.insertNode(It, Q, P);
            cout << "\n";
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        int dis;
        cout << "How many products would you like to display?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Entire Store" << endl;
        cout << "2. Range of Products" << endl;
        cin >> dis;
        system("cls");
        switch(dis)
        {
            case 1:
                pro.displayNode();
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                pro.displayRange();
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        pro.displayNode();
        cout << "What product do you wish to modify? (by item name)" << endl;
        cin.sync();
        getline(cin, It);
        transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
        pro.modifyNode(It);
        break;

    case 4:
        int del;
        cout << "Do you wish to delete one product or more?" << endl;
        cout << "1. One" << endl;
        cout << "2. Range of Products" << endl;
        cout << "3. Entire Store" << endl;
            cin >> del;
            system("cls");
            switch(del)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "What product do you wish to delete? (by item name)" << endl;
                    pro.displayNode();
                    cin.sync();
                    getline(cin,It);
                    transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
                    pro.deleteNode(It);
                    cout << "\nItem successfully deleted." << endl;
                    cout << "\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pro.displayNode();
                    cout << "What range of items do you wish to delete? (by number)" << endl;
                    cout << "START: ";
                    cin >> begin;
                    cout << "END: ";
                    cin >> end;
                    pro.deleteRangeNode(begin, end);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pro.deleteAllNodes();
                    cout << "All items deleted." << endl;
                    break;
            }
        break;

    case 5:
        pro.keepNodes();
        cout << "The inventory has been saved." << endl;
        break;

    case 0:
        cout << "Exiting the program." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    string space1= "                  ";
    string space2= "                                  ";
    int method;
    cout << space1 << "What would you like to do to the store's inventory?" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "1. Add Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "2. Display Products" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "3. Modify Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "4. Delete Product" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "5. Save Inventory" << endl;
    cout << space2 << "0. Exit\n" << endl;
    cout << space2;
    cin >> method;
    return(method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `ItemList` constructor always inserts a new node at the beginning of the list:

```
        ItemList()
        {
            head = new ListNode;
            head->next=nullptr;
        }
```

The node's fields are `std::string`s that are default-constructed to all blanks. You then proceed and create the list, which adds additional nodes. Then you print the entire list. And that's what you see in your output, at the beginning of the list.

If you doubt me, [you should ask your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You asked same question in another place and the solution/fix is also pointed out there. Have you checked that ?

[Extra output during display listnode in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672699/extra-output-during-display-listnode-in-c/36673409#36673409)